# SaltStack: Use directory as source only if it exists

Tags: directory-structure, createprocess, salt-stack

I'd like to know if there's a way of running a SaltStack state only if a directory source is defined in the master.

Basically, I want to allow fo users to put certain configuration files in their `HOME` directory. Most of the users won't have anything special, but some of them might (a custom `.vimrc`, for instance)

What I'd like to do is execute a `file.recurse` for the user's `HOME`directory only if that directory exists in master.

As of now, I have the following:

```
{% for username in pillar['users'] %}

{{ username }}:

  user:
    - present
    - home: /home/{{ username }}
    [  . . . ] # (yadda, yadda, yadda)

# ToDo: Is there a way of not running this AT ALL if the users's directory is
# not present?
/home/{{ username }}:
  file.recurse:
    - user: {{ username }}
    - group: ubuntu
    - source: 
      - salt://users/{{ username }}
    - require:
      - user: {{ username }}

{% endfor %}
```

What I want to do is what in the code appears as the `ToDo`: If there's a directory `salt://users/{{ username }}` in the salt tree (or in the salt master), then execute the `file.recurse` with that directory as the source for the `file.recurse`. Otherwise, just skip that state and use with whatever default content of `$HOME` is has when a user is created (just do nothing, I mean).

I thought adding an `onlyif` clause to the `file.recurse` configuration (something like `- onlyif: test -e salt://users/{{ username }}` would help... but nopes... I also tried to create an empty directory in `salt://users/empty_dir/` and pass it as a default (as described here for a [file.managed](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html)), but that trick doesn't work with `file.recurse` (at least [not yet](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/9304)):

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something similar to

```
{% for username in pillar['users'] %}

{{ username }}:

  user:
    - present
    - home: /home/{{ username }}
    [  . . . ] # (yadda, yadda, yadda)

# NB!!!! POTENTIAL PERF BOTTLENECK
{% if 'users/'+username not in salt['cp.list_master_dirs'](prefix='users') %}
/home/{{ username }}:
  file.recurse:
    - user: {{ username }}
    - group: ubuntu
    - source: 
      - salt://users/{{ username }}
    - require:
      - user: {{ username }}
{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```